# Simple PostGIS ST_Distance query for two points from the same geometry table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, point

*Note: This question was published at Stackoverflow at [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083190/simple-postgis-st-distance-query-for-two-points).*

I have a geometry table `points_table` with `SRID 4326` and a few points in it.

I need to find a distance between a pair of points (features) from this table.

I would like to select one point with `id = X` and another point with `id = Y` and then find a distance between them with `ST_Distance` function.

I know how to query these two points from the database:

```
select * from points_table where id = X or id = Y;
```

But this query returns a result, which I do not know how to pass to `ST_Distance`, because `ST_Distance` takes 2 parameters.

I have tried `Select ST_Distance(select the_geom from points_table where id = X or id = Y);`

But it is obviously wrong.

How can I find the distance between two geometry points (features) from a table?

P.S. All the examples I have found so far [show](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html) the ST_Distance usage with points hardcoded into the arguments of the ST_Distance function. I have not found an example, where ST_Distance is used to calculate a distance between two points from the same table.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to reference your table twice, giving it different aliases:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM points_table a, points_table b
WHERE a.id='x' AND b.id='y';
```